# Looking for opinions on when to unwind loops with if statements

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm wondering when (if ever) I should be pulling if statement out of substantial loops in order to help optimize speed?

```
for(i=0;i<File.NumBits;i++)
  if(File.Format.Equals(FileFormats.A))
    ProcessFormatA(File[i]);
  else
    ProcessFormatB(File[i]);
```

into

```
if(File.Format.Equals(FileFormats.A))
  for(i=0;i<File.NumBits;i++)
    ProcessFormatA(File[i]);
else
  for(i=0;i<File.NumBits;i++)
    ProcessFormatB(File[i]);
```

I'm not sure if the compiler will do this type of optimization for me, or if this is considered good coding practice because I would imagine it would make code much harder to read / maintain if the loops were more complex.

Thanks for any input / suggestions.

Comment: Look at the assembler each produces. There's your answer as to whether the compiler does it for you or not.

Comment: Have you tried both and measured them to see if there's a difference in your environment?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462710/can-c-compilers-optimize-if-statements-inside-for-loops

Comment: it depends.  if ProcessFormatA is a non-inlined or non-vectorizable or ... it will make no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are finished the code and the profiler tells you that the for loops are a bottleneck.  No sooner.

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually processing a file (i.e. reading and/or writing) within your functions, optimizing the `if` is going to be pointless, the file operations will take so much longer, comparatively, than the `if` that you won't even notice the speed improvement.

I would expect that a decent compiler *might* be able to optimize the code - however, it would need to be certain that File.Format can't change in the loop, which could be a big ask.

As I always like to say, write first, optimize later!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely code for maintainability and correctness first. In this case I would be inclined to suggest neither:

```
for(...)
    ProcessFormat(File, Format);
```

Much harder to mess up if all the checks are in one place. You do a better job of confusing your optimizer this way, but generally you want correct code to run slowly rather than incorrect code running quickly.  You can always optimize later if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The two perform the same and read the same, so I'd pick the one that has less code. In fact, this example you give hints polymorphism might be a good fit here to make code simpler and short still.